# Return an array of tuples as AnyObject?

Tags: swift, tuples

Is it possible to return an array of `tuples` as `AnyObject?` or would I have to encapsulate the `tuple` variable within a `class` then return that `class`?

Current structure

```
public typealias Changes = (id:Int!, cors:Bool!)

 struct ClientReturn{
    var error: NSError?
    var json: JSON?
    var mutableReturn: AnyObject?
    var pageResults: PageResults?
}

class func Changes(api_key: String!, startDate: String?, endDate:String?,
    completion: (ClientReturn) -> ()) -> (){
    //content
}

Client.Changes(api_key, startDate: nil, endDate: nil){
    apiReturn in
    var aReturn = apiReturn;
    var changesArray = [Changes]()
    for(var i = 0; i < apiReturn.json!["results"].count; i++ ){
        let json = apiReturn.json!["results"]
        changesArray.append((id: json[i]["id"].int, cors: json[i]["cors"].bool))
    }
    //aReturn.mutableReturn = changesArray as! Changes
    aReturn.mutableReturn = changesArray //ERROR (Cannot assign value of type '[Changes]' to type 'AnyObject?')
    completionHandler(aReturn)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only thing that can be cast up to AnyObject is a class (or a Swift struct that is bridged to some class).

A tuple is not a class. Thus, it cannot be cast up to an AnyObject.

The same thing applies to an array, though by a more roundabout route. An Array is not a class, but it is bridged to NSArray. But an NSArray can contain only classes, i.e. AnyObject elements. Thus, only an array of AnyObject-castables can be cast to AnyObject. A tuple is not a class... You take it from here.

---

Another way of looking at it is this: AnyObject is all about interchange with Objective-C. But tuples are a Swift-only feature: Objective-C knows nothing of them. Thus, an array of tuples cannot be cast to an AnyObject, because it cannot be handed to Objective-C.

Comment: And for more on that topic, see this section of my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/apa.html#_objective_c_objects_and_swift_objects

Comment: Great answer..as always :)